# css style for error message box like facebook sign up

Tags: html, css, facebook

i am working to create error message similar to Facebook signup page error message as shown bellow

[image]

i have tried and got the rectangular box as here

[image]

but i dont know how to get arrow pointed to my particular text ,as shown in Facebook.
my css class

```
.nameAndNumReq {
    color:red;
    width:100px;
    left:180px;
    top:10px;
    font-size:small;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    position: absolute; 
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you've so far...

Comment: Use z-index to place it above other things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ytYaS/1/);
Also, google 'css triangle' technique to understand the working of the arrows. Example: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

```
.bar {
    position: relative;
    background: #C03737;
    border: 1px solid #830303;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.bar:after, .bar:before {
    position: absolute;  
    content: "";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    top: 50%;
}
.bar:before {
    right: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 8px solid #830303; 
}
.bar:after {
    right: -7px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 7px solid #C03737; 
}
```

Comment: it works,, i dont about the css tricks like you guys.. thanks